# Paraview: Multiple csv files to time series

Tags: visualization, paraview

I have multiple CSV files with point-coordinates and, possibly, multiple data values attached to them, i.e., the rows look like

```
x y z data1 data2 ...
```

Is there any possibility to display say 10 of those CSV files in a "time" series in Paraview?

Comment: Welcome to Scicomp.SE. It seems that this question is more appropriated for Paraview forums/mailinglist. I suppose that you are already able of load a single file and plot what you want from it, right? That said... In Paraview, when you have multiple files with the same base name but consecutive enumeration you can plot them over time.

Comment: Well, I posted on the list, too, but so far from my experience, stackexchange is a really good source as well. And you`ve just proven that again: after I renamed the files from fooXXX to foo.XXX, Paraview reckognized them as a time series. Done! Please post this as an answer.

Comment: ParaView is a very common visualization tool for computational projects. I would not really recommend this particular exchange, but stackoverflow has many questions with good answers for this sort of thing.

Comp Sci is more for implementation of mathematical algorithms to get said data to look at in ParaView :) EDIT: also, remember ParaView has a stack trace, so you can look at the trace of what you do in the GUI and then implement a .py script to do what you want. Just run ./pvpython script.py from the /bin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you managed to of load a single file and plot what you want from it you can  try to rename the files. In Paraview, when you have multiple files with the same base name but consecutive enumeration you can plot them over time.